# ASP MVC no match action use next route, is it possible

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Ok here is my RouteConfig:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Projects", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "IgnoreAction",
                url: "{controller}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Projects", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Basically, what I am trying to accomplish here is I would like the server to try and locate a route based on the first route first. However, if there is no matching route, I would like it to just use the controller (i.e. ignore the action). Currently, it is returning a 404 when I send a ValidController/InvalidAction type request.

To be clear:
I would like ValidController/ValidAction to be handled by ValidAction. However, if the request is ValidController/InvalidAction then I would like the request to be handled by ValidController/Index

Comment: @dotnetom Im sorry, I just meant that if the Route is ValidController/InvalidAction then it should just route to ValidController/Index.

Answer (score 1):

The routes configuration in mvc are used in the order that you created it, and you should add the routes the more restrictive to the more general rule.

So that you should put your routes in the following order

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "IgnoreAction",
            url: "{controller}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Projects", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Projects", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

If you still have problems I would recommend you [Gilmpse](http://getglimpse.com/Docs/Routes-Tab) that give you the posibility of "debug" your routes.

Comment: I don't think this would solve my problem. I would like ValidController/ValidAction to be handled by ValidAction. However, if the request is ValidController/InvalidAction then I would like the request to be handled by ValidController/Index

Comment: I test with a default MVC template, If you put the above config and go to /home/index the site gets the default page but if you put home/invalidaction returns a 404 error. The problem with that configuration if you put just / returns a 404 error also.